# Typing field-symbols with ANY or DATA

Tags: abap, typing

I'm currently learning ABAP and wanted to know what is the difference between the following ways of defining a field symbol?

**Method 1**

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs> TYPE data.
```

**Method 2**

```
FIELD-SYMBOLS <fs> TYPE any.
```

I understand that both are typed generically and that the data type will be assigned at runtime.  What I don't understand is how the two are different (or if they are at all).

Answer (score 2):

Yes TYPE ANY and TYPE DATA are exactly the same. Excerpt from [ABAP documentation, Generic ABAP types](https://help.sap.com/http.svc/rc/abapdocu_752_index_htm/7.52/en-US/index.htm?file=abenbuilt_in_types_generic.htm) :

> The generic type **`any`** can, like all generic types listed here except
>   data and object, only be specified directly after TYPE and **has exactly
>   the same effect there as the generic type `data`**. After TYPE REF TO,
>   only data (for fully generic data reference variables) and object (for
>   fully generic object reference variables) can be specified. Specifying
>   REF TO any would define a fully generic reference variable covering
>   data references and object references. This is not currently possible.